# Executando um comando de sistema com parâmetro dentro de uma Function no PostgreSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, funções, trigger

Estou com dificuldade em **criar uma função** no `Postgres` **que execute um comando `shell` do Linux**, com um detalhe: é uma `function` em uma `Trigger after insert` e eu preciso usar algumas colunas do `NEW`.

Em `Mysql`, utilizando o `plugin` "MySQL UDF" foi muito simples, a `trigger` ficou assim:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE result int(10);
   SET result = sys_exec
         (
             '/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/.../regras.php 
              NEW.uniqueid NEW.linkedid NEW.eventtype'
         );
END
```

Agora no `PostgreSQL`, eu instalei a `language PL/sh`, que possibilita a execução de qualquer `script sh`, então tentei a seguinte `function`:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION tarifador_func2() RETURNS TRIGGER
     LANGUAGE plsh
   AS $$
     #!/bin/sh
     /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/...regras.php 
     NEW.uniqueid NEW.linkedid NEW.eventtype
   $$;
```

Ele chega a executar o arquivo `php`, o problema é que essa linguagem não reconhece a nomenclatura `NEW`, aí os valores nos `args` que eu recebo são exatamente as escritas que eu passo no parâmetro.

---

*Alguém conhece alguma forma de utilizar o `NEW` na `PL/sh`?*

---

Outra solução seria passar manualmente os três valores que eu necessito por argumento na criação da `Trigger` e na `function` eu utilizaria `$1`, `$2` e `$3`.
 
Isso seria possível de alguma forma?

Comment: Pergunta foi respondida aqui:
[Running system command with argument in a PostgreSQL function - StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205594/running-system-command-with-argument-in-a-postgresql-function/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Resposta retirada daqui: [Post original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205594/running-system-command-with-argument-in-a-postgresql-function/#answer-43207122).*

---

Você pode acessar alguns valores pelo plsh triggers.

```
UPDATE offers only OLD
INSERT offers only NEW (duh)
DELETE I didn't test
```

Então você obtém esses valores usando argumentos `$1, $2`

Sua `function` seria mais ou menos assim:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tarifador_func2() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plsh
AS $$
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/...regras.php $3 $6 $1

$$;
```

Observe que eu não usei`US $1 $2 $3`, porque a extensão `plsh` despeja TODAS as colunas em argumentos para que sejam declaradas na sua tabela.

Então, você pode fazer algo como `INSERT INTO table1 (column3) VALUES (6);`

E será inferior a `$3` em `plsh`, supondo que esta seja a terceira coluna no quadro.

Como nota, os metadados das "trigger's" estão disponíveis através das `env vars`.